# Is it appropriate to ask a postdoc from another university about the possible research opportunities?

Tags: collaboration

I'm currently a master's student studying theoretical physics. I've been really interested in a research project done by a postdoc from a different university. I was wondering if it would be appropriate if I ask him about the possible research opportunities. I'm not quite sure how I may want to ask, as I'm from a different institution. Should I also let him know I'm just interested in this project and would be happy to volunteer? Thanks!

Comment: You can certainly discuss your interest in his research with him. Just what do you mean by "research opportunities"? Join his group? Apply to his school? I don't understand what "volunteering" might mean.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Thanks for the comment! By that I mean getting involved in his project without formally enrolling at the other university. I'm not quite sure if I would be eligible for funding so I don't know if I should let him know I just would like to have this experience even if it's unpaid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called *networking* --- it's perfectly fine and appropriate and it is a normal part of building a professional career.  Research collaborations across different universities are perfectly normal in academia and there is usually no requirement to be enrolled at, or affiliated with, another university in order to participate in research with academics there.

Researchers at universities are sometimes interested in having people help on their projects (particularly if they are volunteers) but as a Masters student you may or may not have enough background to contribute in a meaningful way.  For these kinds of requests you should look at the matter from the perspective of the other party --- try to think of things you can contribute (taking account of the fact that you are only a Masters student) that can add value to the project.

In any case, it doesn't hurt to express an interest in the research field of another person and ask if there are opportunities.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ask about collaboration it is fine and collaboration with peers is not paid. But, you have to have something to add to the "team" to make this proper. If you just want their help, they will probably decline as it might interfere with their own duties.

If you want to ask them about life as a postdoc it is also fine. They might help or not, depending on how much time they have to spare.

If you want to ask them about whether their current institution is a good place to be it is fine, as well, but if it is really bad, they might not want to reveal their pain. That is an outlier, though.

But, if you are really interested in their work, then some sort of contact might be useful to both of you. Would you give them feedback on a paper in progress? That might be of mutual benefit. And a contact now might lead to more substantial things in the future once you get established. A wide circle of contacts and collaborators is a valuable thing.

But first, think about what you have to offer, not just about what you hope to get.